# tinymce editor breaks on adding a link to content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

For my own cms i am using tinyMce 4.1 to edit content.
Whenever I add a link to my content, the content sort of duplicates. This only happens when i add a link to my content.

As for example:

```
<p>
no link
</p>
```

This gives no duplicates. But when i do this:

```
<a href="/link">Link</a>
```

This will be rendered to:

```
link ">

<a href="/link">Link</a>
```

How do i stop tinymce changing my html?
I tried a lot of options like verify_html, convert_urls, cleanup.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation i found out that the double qoute is the problem here. The html breaks on the ". To prevent this just create entities of your html. For php you can use htmlentities http://php.net/htmlentities